# Simular prompt de javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy intentando hacer una sencilla simulación del prompt de javascript, tengo lo siguiente, que saqué de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("prompt");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 --main-color: #252b39;
 --secondary-color: #00E0C7;
}


.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

.modal-content input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="prompt">Show prompt</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <input type="text" id="promptF">
    <button class="accept">Accept</button>
    <button class="close">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pues lo que busco es la funcionalodad normal del prompt, obtener el valor ingresado en el campo y detectar si se ha presionado el boton cancelar o fuera de la modal, se que existen librerias para crearlos de manera personalizada pero no quisiera utilizar una libreria solo para dar uso al prompt, estoy abierto a soluciones con JQuery tambien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Importante al momento de está respuesta, la versión 75 de FireFox no tiene soporte para dicha etiqueta

Basándome en que buscas la funcionalidad del prompt podemos observar lo siguiente:

- Una de las características del *prompt* es que se superpone y al momento de existir inhabilita cualquier otra acción sobre la página web
- Cuando das click en *OK* sin haber ingresado valor alguno te retorna un *string* vacío
- Si presionas Cancel entonces cierra el *prompt*
- Tanto si ingresas algún valor como si no lo haces al momento de presionar OK el prompt se cierra y mostrará el valor
- No habrái necesidad de algún plugin o incluso de *JQuery* pues HTML5 nos da la posibilidad de crear un modal por medio de dialog tag

Podemos generar un aproximado del prompt así:

```html
  <style>
    #prompt {
      border: 1px solid #F79F1F;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding-top: 40px;
      height: 50px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    }
    #aceptaValor,
    #cierraModal {
      border-radius: 10px;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
    }
    #aceptaValor {
      background-color: #EE5A24;
      color: white;
    }
    #valor {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
<button id="boton-muestra">Muestra el modal</button>
<dialog id="prompt">
  <input type="text" id="valor" />
  <button id="aceptaValor">Ok</button>
  <button id="cierraModal">Cancel</button>
</dialog>
<script>
    let apertura = document.getElementById("boton-muestra")
    let modal    = document.getElementById("prompt")
    let cierraModal   = document.getElementById("cierraModal")
    let valorTecleado = document.getElementById("valor")
    let muestraValor  = document.getElementById("aceptaValor")
    
    apertura.addEventListener("click", () => {
      modal.showModal()
    })
    
    muestraValor.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if(valorTecleado.value === "") {
        console.log("")
        modal.close()
      } else {
        console.log(valorTecleado.value)
        modal.close()
      }
    })
    
    cierraModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
      modal.close()
    })
</script>
```

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [etiqueta dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/dialog)
- [Soporte de la etiqueta dialog en distintos navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#search=dialog)

Comment: Me arroja error al intentar ejecutar el codigo: **modal.showModal is not a function**

Comment: Copiaste mi ejemplo completo? Que navegador usas? @Jalkhov

Comment: Uso Firefox 75.0, ¿De casualidad no falta la función showModal? ¿O es propia de Javascript? @BetaM

Comment: Es propia así que no hay necesidad de construirla

Comment: Deja edito y agrego info sobre el soporte de dicha etiqueta

Comment: @Jalkhov revis el último enlace que acabo de añadir, me parece que el error que te aparece es por el soporte que ahi menciona

Comment: Por lo visto es compatible, pero solo se puede usar si se activa el parametro **dom.dialog_element.enabled** desde **about:config** Esto no representaría ningun problema si solo yo utilizara el codigo, pero a la hora de distribuirlo ¿El usuario deberá habilitarlo? No es lo más practico creo.

Answer (score 3):

Para empezar, tú lo que hablas es sobre un prompt propio. Javascript cuenta con un `prompt()`, le pasas el texto a mostrar y si lo deseas, un valor por defecto. Una vez el usuario toca un botón, esta función retorna el valor final. Entonces, digamos que quieres preguntar la edad del usuario y guardarla en la variable `edad`:

```
edad = prompt("¿Cuál es tu edad?");
```

Volviendo al prompt propio que tú has hecho, te falta implementar el evento click del botón aceptar y también acceder al input.

```
var btnAccept = document.getElementsByClassName("accept")[0];
var input = document.getElementById("promptF");

btnAccept.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //Se mostrará una alerta cuando presiones el botón Aceptar con el contenido del input
    alert(input.value);
})
```

En este caso debes desarrollar más el código para poder hacer algo como en el ejemplo del `prompt()` clásico.
También puedes considerar la posibilidad de usar o ver el código de alguien más, que ya haya hecho un Prompt personalizado. Una opción de ejemplo: [alertify.js](https://github.com/fabien-d/alertify.js/tree/0.3.11)

Es mejor usar addEventListener si deseas tener la posibilidad de tener más de un listener para un evento. Una comparativa de las diferentes formas de añadir EventListeners de StackOverflow en inglés: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("prompt");
var btnAccept = document.getElementsByClassName("accept")[0];
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var input = document.getElementById("promptF");
var texto = "";

btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";
   input.value = "";
}

btnAccept.addEventListener("click", function(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
    texto = input.value;
})

span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
   texto = "";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 --main-color: #252b39;
 --secondary-color: #00E0C7;
}


.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

.modal-content input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="prompt">Show prompt</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <input type="text" id="promptF">
    <button class="accept">Accept</button>
    <button class="close">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```